# Angular Material => set value of mat-select from formControlName

Tags: html, angular, angular-material

My angular version is 7. I am creating a form where have one drop down select to choose a option. My list is working for selecting but when i load page it is not showing pre-defined value. The page is in form to edit user data. Below is my html code,

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Server Name</mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row; let index = index" [formGroupName]="index">
        <mat-form-field>
            <!-- <input class="jminput" matInput formControlName="name" autocomplete="off"> -->
            <mat-select matSelect [formControl]="name">
                <mat-option *ngFor="let item of arr" value="item">{{item}}</mat-option>
            </mat-select>
            <mat-error *ngIf="name.touched && !name.required">
                Server Name is required
            </mat-error>
        </mat-form-field>
    </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
```

When i take the `<input>` in place of `<mat-select>`, it works and display the value whichever comes as initial. So i think **formControlName="name"** is working fine. But it does not work with `<mat-select>`.

Please suggest.

Comment: What do you set on start when you init Control? This value has to be element of `arr` array.

Comment: You should also share the component code. How you set the initial value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

change `value="item"` to `[value]="item"`

Answer (score 2):

You used `[formControl]="name"` instead of `formControlName="name"`. Value setting on start for this control has to be an element of `arr` array.